# What are there 5 google chrome processes that startup with my computer?

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever I start up my windows 7 computer I get these 5 google chrome processes that start. What are they for, how can I disable them?

[image]

I notice when I stop one of them (I don't know how to discern them from each other) that I get a popup that "Google drive has crashed" when I have never installed it and do not have a icon in my task bar "icon popup" (by the time) either. I have also searched my "add remove programs" and cannot find a google drive application. Though I do have google chrome installed.

Comment: Have tried stopping other processes? If so what did chrome say? The google drive might be some extension for a main process because chrome uses multiple threads to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- Go to Chrome settings by clicking the button that looks like three lines towards the upper right of the Chrome window, then selecting `Settings`.
- Type in `background` in the search box towards the upper right.
- Uncheck the option labeled `Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed`.

Answer (score 0):

There is of course a main process that launches on startup, and all the other process's represent any extension or plugin you have. I'm not quite sure why they choose to do it this way but they do. I have also noticed in resource manager that for ever tab you have open it recognizes it as a different process.

Source:[Here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/og-xdL55RJM%5B1-25%5D)